# convert boundingPoly to yolo format

Tags: python, pytorch, bounding-box, google-vision, yolov5

Yolov5 doesn't support segmentation labels and I need to convert it into the correct format.

How would you convert this to yolo format?

```
        "boundingPoly": {
            "normalizedVertices": [{
                "x": 0.026169369
            }, {
                "x": 0.99525446
            }, {
                "x": 0.99525446,
                "y": 0.688811
            }, {
                "x": 0.026169369,
                "y": 0.688811
            }]
        }
```

The yolo format looks like this

```
0 0.588196 0.474138 0.823607 0.441645
<object-class> <x> <y> <width> <height>
```

Comment: Hi. Do you have any other examples? That example doesn't look like a box because both y points have the same value '0.688811' and two of the points don't have a value.

Comment: Hi, it's like that for all of the samples.

Comment: What tool/api created those labels? 

Are you sure it is doing bounding box detection/object detection? It looks like it could be just drawing a line. It looks like it is drawing a vertical line from the top to the bottom about 68% from the left edge. 

The other thing that you are going to need to know to convert something to Yolo format is a class name/id. That is the first value in the yolo format.

Comment: Google Vision. Here is another sample - https://ghostbin.com/hOoaz/raw. Would it be possible to write some Python code as a PoC? The class name/id can be anything.

Comment: That other sample looks better and has enough info to do the conversion. I will try to make a POC today.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll be happy to donate :)

Comment: I have provide a code snippet that will do the conversion as answer. If this resolves your question please accept the answer, upvote, etc. 

Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240297/discussion-between-alexheat-and-john4826).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our back and forth in the comments I have enough info to answer your question. This is output from the Google Vision API. The normalizedVertices are similar to the YOLO format, because they  are "normalized" meaning the coordinates are scaled between 0 and 1 as opposed to being pixels from 1 to n. Still, you need to do some transformation to put into the YOLO format. In the YOLO format, the X and Y values in the 2nd and 3rd columns refer to the center of the bounding box, as opposed to one of the corners.

Here is a code snipped that will sample at https://ghostbin.com/hOoaz/raw into the follow string in YOLO format '0 0.5080664305 0.5624289849999999 0.9786587390000001 0.56914843'

```
#Sample annotation output 
json_annotation = """
      [
        {
          "mid": "/m/01bjv",
          "name": "Bus",
          "score": 0.9459266,
          "boundingPoly": {
            "normalizedVertices": [
              {
                "x": 0.018737061,
                "y": 0.27785477
              },
              {
                "x": 0.9973958,
                "y": 0.27785477
              },
              {
                "x": 0.9973958,
                "y": 0.8470032
              },
              {
                "x": 0.018737061,
                "y": 0.8470032
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
"""

import json
json_object = json.loads(json_annotation, strict=False)

#Map all class names to class id
class_dict = {"Bus": 0}
#Get class id for this record
class_id = class_dict[json_object[0]["name"]]

#Get the max and min values from segmented polygon points 
normalizedVertices = json_object[0]["boundingPoly"]["normalizedVertices"]
max_x = max([v['x'] for v in normalizedVertices])
max_y = max([v['y'] for v in normalizedVertices])
min_x = min([v['x'] for v in normalizedVertices])
min_y = min([v['y'] for v in normalizedVertices])

width = max_x - min_x
height = max_y - min_y 
center_x = min_x + (width/2)
center_y = min_y + (height/2)

yolo_row = str(f"{class_id} {center_x} {center_y} {width} {height}")
print(yolo_row)
```

If you are trying to train a YOLO model there are a few more steps you will need to do: You need to setup the images and annotations in a particular folder structure. But this should help you convert your annotations.